# Finding a loop locus

Tags: geometry

A loop intersects itself once at point  P(0,1), is symmetric about y-axis, with all lines through P cutting the curve at P  and x-axis at B.

Find the locus of looping point A such that $ PA \cdot PB =1. $

EDIT1:

A circle radius $\frac12$ centered at $ (0, \frac32)$ is one extreme, perhaps inadmissible solution because $PB$ is missing.. like to see a proper formulation done.

Comment: I think the locus of the loop will have a constant in it

Comment: So, need to change the problem?( P can be shifted to origin if it simplifies)

Comment: I guess so because I cannot think of a way of removing the constant . Where is this question from?

Comment: What all have you tried?

Comment: I devised it;  $( x^2 + (y-1)^2) \cdot  ( 1/m^2 +1) $ should be constant for all $m,$ but is n't the way to go..

Comment: Yes even I am stuck with that constant

Comment: I guess the locus will be formulated with that constant only. Cannot think of a way to remove it

Comment: Ok, could we then first see in comment at first and then take as answer later?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29081/discussion-between-narasimham-and-remember-me).